# Bus to Train for Trip from Riva del Garda to Verona

Tags: trains, buses

My son is taking a one day break from a study abroad program and wants to spend it in Verona (His group will be in Riva del Garda.)

The tentative plan is to take the Trentino Trasporti bus Route B332 from a stop close to his hotel (Riva V.Carducci H.Liberty), but several stops after the main station. How often do these buses fill up? Are they usually on time? Would he be in danger of missing a train connection (25 minute allowance) in Rovereto?